# pyinstaller versiontext file error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I keep getting this error when i try to load a versiontext file for my program, its a gui, pyinstaller actually creates an exe without the version file but when i provide a version file it runs into errors.

```
  File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.2-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
  exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 28, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.2-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 407, in __init__
  self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.2-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 178, in __postinit__
  self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.2-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 496, in assemble
  versioninfo.SetVersion(tmpnm, self.versrsrc)
  File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.2-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\utils\win32\versioninfo.py", line 557, in SetVersion
  win32api.UpdateResource(hdst, pefile.RESOURCE_TYPE['RT_VERSION'], 1, vs.toRaw())
  File "C:\Users\Afro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.2-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\utils\win32\versioninfo.py", line 160, in toRaw
  nm = pywintypes.Unicode(u'VS_VERSION_INFO')
  TypeError: must be impossible<bad format char>, not str.
```

Here's my version file

```
# UTF-8

VSVersionInfo(
  ffi=FixedFileInfo(
    # filevers and prodvers should be always a tuple with four items: (1, 2, 3, 4)
    # Set not needed items to zero 0.
  filevers=(96, 12, 19, 1),
  prodvers=(1, 0, 0, 0),
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the valid bits 'flags'
  mask=0x3f,
# Contains a bitmask that specifies the Boolean attributes of the file.
  flags=0x0,
# The operating system for which this file was designed.
# 0x4 - NT and there is no need to change it.
  OS=0x4,
# The general type of file.
# 0x1 - the file is an application.
  fileType=0x1,
# The function of the file.
# 0x0 - the function is not defined for this fileType
  subtype=0x0,
# Creation date and time stamp.
  date=(6, 2016)
  ),
kids=[
  StringFileInfo(
    [
    StringTable(
      u'040904b0',
      [StringStruct(u'CompanyName', u'getSERIES, VA 00001'),
      StringStruct(u'ProductName', u'getSERIES'),
      StringStruct(u'ProductVersion', u'1, 0, 0, 0'),
      StringStruct(u'InternalName', u'getSERIES'),
      StringStruct(u'OriginalFilename', u'getSERIES.exe'),
      StringStruct(u'FileVersion', u'96, 12, 19, 1'),
      StringStruct(u'FileDescription', u'Get it'),
      StringStruct(u'LegalCopyright', u'Copyright 2016.'),
      StringStruct(u'LegalTrademarks', u'getSERIES is a registered trademark of HackAfro Inc.'),])
  ]),
      VarFileInfo([VarStruct(u'Translation', [1033, 1200])])
  ]
  )
```

what did i get wrong? Thanks